# Why h1 and p looks almost the same size when you set them to 2em (font-size: 2em) when em is the units of x times of the font size

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have some HTML pages with custom fonts and in order to let it looks nicer I usually sized up the text using css, but as I look through the [document](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) they said em is the x times of the original font size and I think great this is what I'm going to use but as I use it, it came out result like below:

```css
* {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Header
</h1>
<p>
  Paragraph
</p>
```

Notice that the result it's showing is that `h1` and `p` is almost the same size except `h1` is thicker and darker, but why will this happened isn't 2em meant 2x larger than original text? Why the `h1` scales down and `p` scales up?

P.S. In order to let the result shown properly I set the font-size to 1.5em instead of 2em or it'll be too large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the font-size in `em` you are setting it relative to the font-size of the **parent** element.

Since both elements have the same parent element, they get the same font-size.

The differences are due to them having different values for other properties (such as font-weight).

---

You are not setting it relative to the font-size it would have had without that style rule. The Cascade doesn't work like that.

---

> as I look through the document they said…

**Do not trust W3Schools!** They are frequently wrong.

Look at [the official specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units):

> The 'em' unit is equal to the computed value of the 'font-size' property of the element on which it is used. **The exception is when 'em' occurs in the value of the 'font-size' property itself, in which case it refers to the font size of the parent element**. It may be used for vertical or horizontal measurement. (This unit is also sometimes called the quad-width in typographic texts.)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  It scales it based on the font size of the parent element.

Be sure you have declared what that original size is for your body section in the css.
You might also right-click on your elements and click "inspect" in your browser. This will reveal what styles are being applied.  You might have some font-weight that is being applied to the headers

Comment: "It scales it based on the font size of the body" — No! The parent element, not the body.

Comment: Excuse me Dean, as my target I used em is for a mobile responsive design if I setted a pixel value or some static sized won't it become non-mobile friendly?

Comment: You can set the pixel size for at least the parent element, for example the body.  And then you can use media query breakpoints to change that parent elements pixel size for smaller screens and then everything will scale nicely on mobile devices. Here is a link about media query breakpoints to get you started: https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/

Comment: You might also compare em sizes and rem sizes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Rems

Comment: So you meant you need to set a static value in order to let em works but is there any way to get the value of font size setting of client's browser/OS? since I've tried set the html with font-size:100% but now working

Comment: According to this page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Rems) the default browser setting is 1em or 10px. You might verify the difference between em sizing and rem sizing. Because the em size is the parent of that element where the rem size is a reference to the global page element.

Comment: So pixel will auto scale down if you're in smaller screen? If not why all the browser has default of 10px?